# Odd AngularJS 1.5 behaviour in Chrome of nested directive in component

Tags: jquery, angularjs, google-chrome, sparklines

I have an AngularJS directive that creates a Sparkline, which I then use inside a couple of modules. The app behaves as expected in Firefox (51..), however when viewed in the Google Chrome browser (56..), the app fails to deliver the desired graphic.

Note that I have tested the actual app from a server and this is not a Cross origin requests issue. Furthermore, upon inspection, no errors are reported on console.

[image: Image showing output in two browsers]

This plunker reproduces my original issue: https://plnkr.co/edit/K9wO5Ibx1Uk8ygkOUGU6?p=preview

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.sparkline.js"></script>
    <script src="app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="ab-help.module.js"></script>
    <script src="ab-help.component.js"></script>
    <script src="ab-spkline.directive.js"></script>
  </head>
<body ng-app="abMyapp">
    <h2>Testing sparkline directive via component in angular </h2>
    <p>This is outside the ab-help tags</p>
    <spk-line data="30, 1, 14, 10, 8, 15, 6, 13, 2"></spk-line>
    <ab-help></ab-help>
  </body>
</html>
```

The various **.js** parts are compressed below:

```
// Define the 'app' module
angular.module('abMyapp', ['abHelp']); //note in my original app more modules are injected here, example on plunker only shows one!

// Define the `abHelp` module
angular.module('abHelp', []);

// Register `abHelp` component, along with its associated controller and template
angular.
module('abHelp').
component('abHelp', {
    templateUrl: 'ab-help.template.html',
    controller: function(){
      this.myData = "1, 1, 4, 14, 4, 15, 6, 23, 4";
    }
});

//template
<p>This is from inside component</p>
<spk-line data="3, 1, 4, 10, 8, 5, 6, 3, 4"></spk-line> <br>
<spk-line data="{{ $ctrl.myData }}"></spk-line>
```

The all-important Sparkline directive with thanks for http://jsfiddle.net/NAA5G/ and of course http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-about, & JQuery, Angular!

```
angular.module('abMyapp').directive("spkLine", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      data: "@"
    },

    compile: function(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
      tElement.replaceWith("<span>" + tAttrs.data + "</span>");
      return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        attrs.$observe("data", function(newValue) {
          element.html(newValue);
          element.sparkline('html', {
            type: 'line'
          });
        });
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually sorted by useing release 2.1.2 of the jquery sparkline. This has a tooltips issue which I have raised with [issue #188](https://github.com/gwatts/jquery.sparkline/issues)

Thanks for having a look.